# Creating a 4 column table in python

Tags: python, file, input, datatable, output

I have the following data:

```
1.
Little Grebe
Tachybaptus ruficollis
टीबुकली
2.
Great Crested Grebe
Podiceps cristatus
मोठी टीबुकली
3.
Black-necked Grebe
Podiceps nigricollis
काळया मानेची टीबुकली
4.
Spot-billed Pelican
Pelecanus philippensis
ठीपक्याच्या चोचीचा झोळीवाला
```

I need to create a table which looks something like:

1. (tab) Little Grebe (tab) Tachybaptus ruficollis (tab) टीबुकली

Right now I have code which looks like:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")

for i in range(2210):  # 2210 is the number of lines in the file
    print(' ')
    for j in range(4):
        print(f.readline(30)+'\t', end='')
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over 4 inside the row iterator which means you end up running `f.readline()` 8840 times which may be intended. And no row is treated differently. You also need to strip away the newline character if you ar using readline. Otherwise it is also printed. Some small changes to your code is enough to make it work:

```py
f = open("test.txt", "r")

for i in range(2210):  # 2210 is the number of items in file
    for j in range(3):
        # Three lines printed with tab
        print(f.readline().strip(), end='\t')
    # And one finishing the row
    print(f.readline().strip())
```

If you know every new item will start with a number and a dot, then you can use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find newlines that's not followed by this and replace with tab.

```py
import re
with open('test.txt', "r") as f:
    print(re.sub(r'\n(?!\d+\.)', r'\t', f.read()))
```

Comment: I mean the string from the file including row breaks

Comment: So right now, there are some instances where there are only 2 names after the number, so the table columns are mismatched. Is there a way to handle such edge cases? My thought was - once you encounter a number you check if the next number occurs after 3 lines, if not then put blanks in those many columns.

Comment: @CheaterLetsGO Good idea. Added a solution that at least change row on next number but doesn't put extra blanks in missing columns

Comment: @CheaterLetsGO If you find the answer useful you can mark it as useful and I get better reputation :)

Comment: I did. It says - Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @CheaterLetsGO oh.  I didn’t know that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Just try this code, I hope it will help you.**

```
crimefile = open("/home/developer/task.txt", "r")

i = 0

line_list = crimefile.readlines()
for line_l in line_list:
    if i == 3:
        print(line_l.strip(), end='\n')
        i = 0
    else:
        print(line_l.strip(), end=' ')
        i = i+1
```

**I got this result:-**

```
1.  Little Grebe    Tachybaptus ruficollis  टीबुकली
2.  Great Crested Grebe Podiceps cristatus  मोठी टीबुकली
3.  Black-necked Grebe  Podiceps nigricollis    काळया मानेची टीबुकली
4.  Spot-billed Pelican Pelecanus philippensis  ठीपक्याच्या चोचीचा झोळीवाला
```